# Z-order of WinAPI child windows

Tags: winapi

The [WinAPI docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#z-order) state:

> *A child window is grouped with its parent in z-order.*

Two questions:

1. What does "grouped" mean in this context?
2. How is the z-order of siblings determined?

I'm trying to understand the precise z-order / draw order of a complex hierarchy of windows under a single top-level window for the purposes of doing blended rendering via D3D / DirectComposition of child windows onto parent windows.

Comment: Yeah, that's clumsily worded.  This is about the "single list", a child window always belongs to its parent.  So the Z-order of the parent implicitly determines the Z-order of its children, as compared to other toplevel windows.  Child windows maintain a Z-order among each other as well, implicitly determined by the order of their CreateWindowEx calls.

Comment: So it means children are always drawn on top of parents?

Comment: Child windows are confined to the client area of their respective parents. They are drawn on top of their respective parent windows' client areas. [Owned windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows) on the other hand are always drawn on top of their owners.